# Fill out form on external webpage from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to fill out a form on an external webpage based on values from a current page when a user clicks the chrome extension I created.

So what I am trying to do is open the page and pass a message first using this from a popup.js file.

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://localhost:49177/ProDATA/Add.aspx"},function(tab){  
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {FirstName: FirstName}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell); })
    });
```

Then on the add.aspx page which would be in a different domain as the page the user is located on I try to do this.

```
//add listener for chrome extension
    var FirstName = '';
    function LoadEventListener()
    {
        alert('test');

        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, response) {                
            FirstName = request.FirstName;
            alert(FirstName);
        });
    }
```

I load "LoadEventListener" from the body onload event. and the alert "test" shows, therefore it is indeed loading, however I do not see the "FirstName" alert.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Priviledged chrome.* API won't work by default on web pages in modern Chrome.

  The url should be explicitly allowed via ["externally_connectable"](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage) in the manifest (see that link for code examples).

  Or Use [tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to [inject](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) the DOM access code instead of `tabs.sendRequest`.
- The doc says that [tabs.sendRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendRequest) is deprecated since Chrome 33. Use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` instead.

Comment: thanks for the response, however I still can't get it to work. It seems that these methods are mainly used to pass data from the webpage to the extension, I want to do it backwards.

Comment: Essentially I want to create a tab and grab data from wherever the user clicked the extension and populate fields on the newly created tab.

Comment: Then declare a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that will be automatically injected on `http://localhost:49177/ProDATA/Add.aspx` url and in that script you will be able to use `chrome.runtime.onMessage`.

Comment: actually got the sendMessage to work, it took some time to learn how that worked but it finally did :) thanks!